# taurus installation using homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, taurus

I'm trying to install Taurus using home brew but I keep getting this error.

```
    Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/doc
/usr/local/share/info
/usr/local/share/locale
/usr/local/share/man
/usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/local/share/man/man3
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7
/usr/local/share/man/man8
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/var/log

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/log

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/doc /usr/local/share/info /usr/local/share/locale /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1 /usr/local/share/man/man3 /usr/local/share/man/man5 /usr/local/share/man/man7 /usr/local/share/man/man8 /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/var/log
```

I tried using the `sudo chown -R $(whoami)`  , but it shows operation not permitted.

I don't know if is something related to home brew or the taurus installation.

I'm pretty new to using the terminal, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
The homebrew package files were in another user on my laptop.
I uninstalled homebrew and taurus and reinstalled them in my current user, and it worked!!